# Hide all the rowspan column cells in jQuery or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the below code, the first `td` has `rowspan` applied making the rest of the cells in that columns shift to the right. Here I want the cells in that column to hide instead of shifting, except the first cell which has rowspan. How do I do that in jQuery or CSS.

So, I want all the cells having **1** to be **hidden** except the one which was spanned.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a191jffw/28/

```css
th, td{
  width:70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="result">
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want all td with number 1 to hide?

Comment: Yes, but not the one which was spanned.

Comment: Added a solution, hope its what your looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what your looking for.

```
$("table tr td[rowspan]").each(function() {
  var i = $("table tr td").index($(this))
  $("table tbody tr").each(function(_, x) {
    $(x).children('td:eq(' + i + ')').not('[rowspan]').hide();
  });
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("table tr td[rowspan]").each(function() {
  var i = $("table tr td").index($(this))
  $("table tbody tr").each(function(_, x) {
    $(x).children('td:eq(' + i + ')').not('[rowspan]').hide();
  });
})
```

```css
th, td{
  width:70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to provide a solution with pure javascript. This should also work even if you change rowspan value.

```
(function(){
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  var td=document.querySelector('#result td[rowspan]');
  var n=Number(td.getAttribute('rowspan'));
  var tr=td.parentElement;
  for(var i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    tr=tr.nextElementSibling;
    tr.firstElementChild.style.display="none";
  }
});
})()
```

```js
(function(){
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  var td=document.querySelector('#result td[rowspan]');
  var n=Number(td.getAttribute('rowspan'));
  var tr=td.parentElement;
  for(var i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    tr=tr.nextElementSibling;
    tr.firstElementChild.style.display="none";
  }
});
})()
```

```css
th, td{
  width:70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="result">
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a191jffw/29/) using jquery and css 'visibilty'.

```
$('table td').each( function(){
    if ( !$(this).attr('rowspan') ) {
    $(this).css({
    'visibility' : 'hidden'
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I perfer css to javascript, for those users which might be anti-javascript. With that said I'm throwing my solution out there.

```
tr > td:nth-child(1){
  display:none;
}
tr:first-child > td:first-child{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help you.

```
$('#result td').each(function() {
    if ((!$(this).attr('rowspan') && ($(this).html() == 1))) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

```js
$('#result td').each(function() {
    if ((!$(this).attr('rowspan') && ($(this).html() == 1))) {
     $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
 <table border="1">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```